# Will an old Eclipse RCP plugin work with Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I am having very basic doubt about Eclipse Che. Can an old Eclipse plugin (developed for Eclipse 3.x) be deployed into Eclipse Che?

Answer (score 3):

> Can an old Eclipse plugin (developed for Eclipse 3.x) be deployed into Eclipse Che?

**No.** Eclipse Che is an entirely new code base that does not use Eclipse IDE Plug-ins. Neither for Eclipse 4.x for that matter.