# How we can port existing Eclipse Editor Plugin to Eclipse Che?

Tags: xtext, eclipse-che

We have our domain specific language based on xtext. 
For representation of language, we have our own editor in Eclipse. This editor is basically Eclipse plugin. **Is there any way to port this eclipse editor plugin to Che?**

As this is eclipse plugin, it's tightly coupled with the IResource model and Che don't support for IResource model, Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38027405/1639625 (According to this, existing plugins can not simply be used in Che, but this question is about what's needed to convert them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Eclipse Che 5.0](https://che.eclipse.org/release-notes-eclipse-che-5-0-fde5626194f1#.h6mqunm4v) and [Xtext 2.11](https://typefox.io/xtext-2-11-is-released) released in early 2017 it is possible to have Xtext editors in Eclipse Che via the [Language Server protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol).

[Christian Dietrich](https://blogs.itemis.com/author/christian-dietrich) of Itemis wrote a blog post about this recently with more details: https://blogs.itemis.com/en/how-to-get-started-with-xtext-language-servers-and-che

And of course, since Xtext is built on EMF, paying attention to the work of EMF on Che is important too, have a look at this series of blog posts, also from Feb 2017 http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2017/02/08/emf-support-for-che-day-0-motivation-and-getting-started/